# Get rid of `for` loops to construct $L$

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I have a kind of implicit characterization of the adjacency matrix $L$ of a directed line graph of an undirected graph on $n$ vertices (each edge in the undirected graph is represented by a pair of directed edges, back and forth). Given $A$ the adjacency matrix of the undirected graph I found that the matrix element at $(ab_n,bc_n)$ ($xy_n$ is a $n$-ary two digit number) of $L$ looks like the following:
$$
L_{ab_n,bc_n}=\langle a|A|b \rangle \! \langle b|A|c \rangle,
$$
where $a,b,c\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. I can use three `for`loops (for $a,b,c$ each running from $1$ to $n$) to construct $L$, but is it possible to do that directly, by using *e.g.* superoperator formalism?

**EDIT** If it helps: An answer for bipartite cubic planar graphs is fair enough...

We can use a permutation matrix $S$ to get
 $$
L_{ab_n,bc_n}=S\circ L_{ab_n,cb_n},
$$
where the latter has the same structure as the following kronecker product:
$$
\pmatrix{1&\cdots& 1\\ \vdots&&\vdots\\1&\cdots& 1}\otimes \text{diag}(1,\dots,1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is not not really an answer to the stated question. I posted this to hopefully clarify the situation so that someone else will find a proper solution. However, I did find something interesting that might help.

First, we have $A$, an $n\times n$ adjacency matrix for an undirected graph. Because this is an undirected graph, $A$ is symmetric, i.e. $A_{i, j} = A_{j, i}$ (since an edge from $i$ to $j$ in an undirected graph is the same as the edge from $j$ to $i$), or $A^T = A$.

OP wishes to generate $L$, an $n^2 \times n^2$ adjacency matrix for matrix $A$. Row or column $i$ in $L$ shall correspond to row $r$, column $c$ in $A$, with $i = r a + c$. This can be defined as
$$L_{n a + b,\; n b + c} = A_{a,b} A_{b,c}$$

The original question, if I've understood correctly, is whether or not there is a simpler way to calculate $L$ than explicitly element-wise as above.

At least $(n-1)/n$ of it will be filled with zeroes, as can be expected, since at most $n^3$ of the $n^4$ elements are assigned to using the above element-wise assignment.

It turns out that $L$ has a very explicit pattern. For example, if $n = 3$, then
$$L = \left [ \begin{matrix}
A_{11} A_{11} & A_{11} A_{12} & A_{11} A_{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{12} A_{21} & A_{12} A_{22} & A_{12} A_{23} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{13} A_{31} & A_{13} A_{32} & A_{13} A_{33} \\
A_{21} A_{11} & A_{21} A_{12} & A_{21} A_{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{22} A_{21} & A_{22} A_{22} & A_{22} A_{23} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{23} A_{31} & A_{23} A_{32} & A_{23} A_{33} \\
A_{31} A_{11} & A_{31} A_{12} & A_{31} A_{13} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{32} A_{21} & A_{32} A_{22} & A_{32} A_{23} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & A_{33} A_{31} & A_{33} A_{32} & A_{33} A_{33}
\end{matrix} \right ]$$

The possibly nonzero entries in $L$ form $n$ $n\times n$ matrices. Let's call these $P_1$ through $P_n$, so that $P_1$ defines the $n$ leftmost columns in $L$, $P_2$ the next $n$ columns, and so on, with $P_n$ defining the rightmost $n$ columns in $L$. Note that each $P_i$ defines every $n$'th row, starting at row $i$. (I do not know of a simple way to mathematically represent the row distribution from $P_i$ to $L$, though.)

It is now rather obvious that
$$P_i = A_{col=i} A_{row=i}$$
where $A_{col=i}$ refers to the column $i$ of $A$ as a column vector, and $A_{row=i}$ refers to the row $i$ of $A$ as a row vector.

Furthermore, since $A$ is symmetric, $P_i$ are too.

(Programmatically, this means that since entries in $A$ are binary or boolean (connected / not connected), each zero entry clears an entire row and entire column in $P_i$, and since $A_{col=i} = A_{row=i}^T$, a single consecutive memory chunk needs to be examined to construct each $P_i$. Personally, I wouldn't even compute $L$ explicitly, but use a function that computes any requested entries as needed from $A$, using short-circuit logic.)

As I mentioned above, I don't know of a neat way to mathematically express the construction of the $P_i$ and their distribution into $L$, in case that is what the OP really needs, but perhaps someone else can construct a suggestion?

Comment: +1 thanks, the need to compute $L$ turned out in this [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34649/discussion-between-will-orrick-and-draks), if you're interested...

Comment: @draks...: Eww. My weak math-fu wilted under that assault. (I know just enough to follow the discussion, but nowhere near enough experience or knowledge to make any sort of useful suggestions.) I do have some experience in and ideas for C data structures and code that could populate $L$ efficiently (but still $O(N^3)$ for the worst case, completely connected graph, $A_{i,j}=1$), either as a dense or as a sparse matrix, but I do not think it would help with the underlying problem. I have an "itch" that tells me there *is* simpler formulation for describing $L$, I just cannot grasp it.

Comment: hey thanks for contributing, I think I can use some of your ideas...

Comment: @draks...: Let me know if you want me to add some example C code. In particular, for larger $n$ the cache/memory bandwidth becomes the bottleneck for sure, so you probably want to use a per-bit representation for $A$. For $L$, that means the direct calculation from $A$ is a logical and operation (short-circuited) instead of a multiplication, and definitely better than calculating the entire $L$.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, sorry the delay, but don't your $n$ $P_k$ span kind of rank-3-tensor, since it operates on a kind of a kronecker product $A\otimes A$? I also used "short-circuit logic", some example C code from your side would be nice, if you still have...

Comment: $P_i=A_{col=i}A_{col=i}^T=A_{row=i}^TA_{row=i}$ are $n$ projectors, right?